Reset the Compiler optimisation settings for a specific file to defaults
I have an Eclipse project (in NXP's MCUXpress environment, but I do not think that matters) in which I have modified the compiler optimisation settings for a specific file.  I did this by right clicking the file..properties and modifying in the subsequent dialog.
I now want to undo this and have this file use the optimisation settings from the project.
I cannot see a way to do this in the GUI.  In the .project file I can see the following:
<fileInfo id="com.crt.advproject.config.exe.debug.575077075.1677142664" name="expt.c" rcbsApplicability="disable" resourcePath="source/expt.c" toolsToInvoke="com.crt.advproject.gcc.exe.debug.542524617.1359417607">
    <tool id="com.crt.advproject.gcc.exe.debug.542524617.1359417607" name="MCU C Compiler" superClass="com.crt.advproject.gcc.exe.debug.542524617">
        <option id="com.crt.advproject.gcc.exe.debug.option.optimization.level.1470996910" name="Optimization Level" superClass="com.crt.advproject.gcc.exe.debug.option.optimization.level" value="gnu.c.optimization.level.optimize" valueType="enumerated"/>
        <inputType id="com.crt.advproject.compiler.input.1260736943" superClass="com.crt.advproject.compiler.input"/>
    </tool>
</fileInfo>

Can I just delete this section from the .project file? Or should I just delete the option line.  I could "just try it", but it is not easy to figure out if I have stored up some problems for the future! Are there any other places I need to fix up as well?
